# Using godoc with some annotatinos/filters

Tags: go

We are using `godoc` to our lib and we saw all the public method in the doc as expected.

**My questions are:**

1. If there is a way to remove from the doc public method without making them private? with some annotation maybe?
2. If I provide package and in the package there is *more* then one file and I want to expose in the doc *only* `fileA.go` and not `C.go`, `D.go`, etc, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so, but not 100% sure. Couldn't find anything pointing to options like this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. No

General rule in Go: No there are no flags, annotations, triggers, whatever. Especially not if not documented.